# Update the table with latest time in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I am new to SQL, I am not able to solve this scenario.

I have this table:

```
Number      code    d_date 
---------------------------------------
2054330994  SP41   11/23/2020 10:14:43
2054330994  SP41   11/23/2020 10:14:44
2054330994  SP41   11/23/2020 10:14:45
2054330994  SP41   11/23/2020 10:14:46
2054330994  SP41   11/23/2020 10:14:47
2054330994  SP41   11/23/2020 10:14:48
2054330994  SP41   11/23/2020 10:14:49
2054330994  SP41   11/23/2020 10:14:49
2054330994  SP41   11/23/2020 10:14:49
2054330994  SP41   11/23/2020 10:14:43
2054330995  SP41   11/23/2020 10:14:43
2054330995  SP41   11/23/2020 10:14:52
2054330995  SP41   11/23/2020 10:14:43
2054330995  SP41   11/23/2020 10:14:52
2054330995  SP41   11/23/2020 10:14:52
```

Expected results:

```
2054330994  SP41   11/23/2020 10:14:49
2054330995  SP41   11/23/2020 10:14:52
```

We can see there is many duplicate entry.

My issue: I need to keep the number, which `d_date` has latest entry. Remaining entry related this number we need to removed from same table.

Sorry I am not able to get going on this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sample data is great, but you also need to _specify_ the expected result.

Comment: Exactly; is the result only one row (with the latest D_DATE), or 8 rows (because only the last 3 rows are "duplicates", but you want to keep the first 7 rows whose times aren't duplicate)? Also, do you need it just as a SELECT, or do you want to DELETE unwanted rows from the table?

Comment: we need the result in same table as :
2054330994  SP41   11/23/2020 10:14:49

Remaining enrtry should be removed as the Number is same.

Comment: Since you know what the expected result is, edit your question and _specify_ it!

Comment: what if the duplicate appears at the maximum date value?

Comment: Add some rows with different Number and code values to the sample data, and adjust the expected result (if needed.)

Comment: It is a basic aggregation. Please, show **your** attempt

Answer (score 1):

To query without the dups you could aggregate on Number & code

```
SELECT "Number", code
, MAX(d_date) AS d_date
FROM your_table
GROUP BY "Number", code
ORDER BY "Number", code
```

Or use ROW_NUMBER

```
SELECT "Number", code, d_date
FROM
(
    SELECT "Number", code, d_date
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY "Number", code ORDER BY d_date DESC) AS rn
    FROM your_table
) q
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY "Number", code;
```

To remove the dups from the table, then row_number can also be used for that.

> ```
> DELETE 
> FROM your_table
> WHERE rowid IN (
>    SELECT rowid
>    FROM (
>     SELECT "Number", code, d_date
>     , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY "Number", code 
>                          ORDER BY d_date DESC) AS rn
>     FROM your_table
>    ) q WHERE rn > 1
> );
> ```

> ```
> SELECT *
> FROM your_table
> ORDER BY "Number", code, d_date
> ```

| Number | CODE | D_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2054330994 | SP41 | 23-NOV-20 10.14.49.000000 |
| 2054330995 | SP41 | 23-NOV-20 10.14.52.000000 |

Demo on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=810ccc283bb6c20af4805dc1b8457c82)*

Comment: "_Remaining entry related this number we need to removed from same table._" makes me suspect OP perhaps wants to _DELETE_ rows.

Comment: Okay, not sure yet, but you could be right.

Comment: @jarlh we want to remove remaining row

Comment: @CrazyCoder Included a DELETE statement.

Comment: You can make the query simpler [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=6f701ec4266cbacf0bc14bbb5596f128) as you don't need to select all the other columns and don't need to give the sub-query an alias that you never use.

Answer (score 0):

Delete from the table, as you said:

Before:

```
SQL> select * from test order by num, code, d_date;

       NUM CODE D_DATE
---------- ---- --------------------
       994 SP41 11/23/2020 10:14:43
       994 SP41 11/23/2020 10:14:43
       994 SP41 11/23/2020 10:14:46
       994 SP41 11/23/2020 10:14:49
       994 SP41 11/23/2020 10:14:49
       995 SP41 11/23/2020 10:14:43
       995 SP41 11/23/2020 10:14:52
       995 SP41 11/23/2020 10:14:52
       995 SP41 11/23/2020 10:14:52

9 rows selected.
```

Delete:

```
SQL> delete from test a
  2    where a.rowid not in
  3              (select rowid
  4                 from (select row_number () over (partition by num, code
  5                                                  order by d_date desc) rn,
  6                              rowid
  7                       from test
  8                      )
  9                where rn = 1
 10              );

7 rows deleted.
```

After:

```
SQL> select * from test order by num, code, d_date;

       NUM CODE D_DATE
---------- ---- --------------------
       994 SP41 11/23/2020 10:14:49
       995 SP41 11/23/2020 10:14:52

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried below query and its seems working as expected.

```
DELETE FROM table_name WHERE d_date != (SELECT MAX(t2.d_date) FROM table_name t2 WHERE t2.number = table_name.number);
```

I don't know in which condition it will fail but as of now with my current scenario it is working as exprcted.

Comment: I disagree. Your query will keep ALL (duplicate) rows whose D_DATE column is equal to MAX(D_DATE) per NUMBER (BTW, what an unfortunate column name; it is reserved for data type so you can't use it as a column name). Result you expect is only TWO rows per each NUMBER. Therefore, either what you posted so far was misleading (and unfair towards the community), or query you posted is wrong (and I'm right).